# SnowFlake Python package is converting table name from small case to Upper case

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table in snowflake in lower case , my table name is `fulltransactions` but when I use snowflake connector is converting my `select * from DATA.PUBLIC.fulltransactions` to `select * from DATA.PUBLIC.FULLTRANSACTIONS` thus I get response as no table found or not authorised.

What might be the reason behind it?

Comment: Are you sure your table in Snowflake is in lower case? Because if it is, you would have to use double quotes to access it, like this ```select * from DATA.PUBLIC."fulltransactions"```. Otherwise, it doesn't matter whether you write the table name with lower case or upper case. Maybe the error refers to something else.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment, please try this:

select * from DATA.PUBLIC."fulltransactions";

test:
`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "fulltransactions" (col1 varchar);`
`INSERT INTO  "fulltransactions" values('test');`

`SELECT * FROM SNOW_SANDBOX.PUBLIC.FULLTRANSACTIONS;`

```
SQL compilation error: Object 'SNOW_SANDBOX.PUBLIC.FULLTRANSACTIONS' does not exist or not authorized.
```

`SELECT * FROM SNOW_SANDBOX.PUBLIC."fulltransactions";`

| COL1 |
| --- |
| test |

If you would like to make your table not require case sensitivity you can rename the table:

`ALTER TABLE "fulltransactions" RENAME TO FULLTRANSACTIONS;`

Rerunning the original query now works:

`SELECT * FROM SNOW_SANDBOX.PUBLIC.FULLTRANSACTIONS;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to proceed without needing to rename the tables, because sometimes, you just don't have the necessary database privileges.

Here's the code

```
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd

# connect to Snowflake
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=USER,
        password=PASSWORD,
        account=ACCOUNT,
        warehouse= WAREHOUSE,
        database = DATABASE,
        schema = SCHEMA,
        role=ROLE
    )
cur = con.cursor()

# define query, choose one of the two below 
# depending on how your table is named in Snowflake

# 1. if your table is DB.SCHEMA.TABLE
q = """select * from TABLE""" 

# OR 2. if your table is DB.SCHEMA."table"
q = """select * from "table" """


# retreive data from Snowflake
try:
    result = cur.execute(q).fetchall()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    cur.close()
    con.close()

# assuming results are to be consumed as a dataframe
col_names = [col[0] for col in cur.description]
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = col_names)
```